# Which layout for background with tiles FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm trying to create a background with a 60x60 tile as my background on FXML. Which Pane type do you think I should use? It will look similar to this one:

[image]

Comment: You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html with a background repeat.

Comment: [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html), [TilePane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) are two.

Comment: I've done it with multiple HBoxes. Thanks for the answers.